# Cors issue with fetching aws lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cors

[image]

I have a frontend build with react and I'm trying to fetch a request from my aws lambda function. [image]

Here is what I have done so far.

I used information below to add my headers.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

```js
return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
        message: response.choices[0].message.content,
    }),
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST"
    },
};
```

I have also enabled cors on my api gateway.
[image]

Comment: Why didn't you finish on API gateway?  The error message indicates that it's not done.

Comment: I don't know how to fix the Add access-control-allow-origin. i just followed through with the gui on enable cors